# Read column variable name and mapped it to @Column annotaion in @Entity class Dynamically in Spring JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

we have spring boot application and we are dealing with situation where number of column(s) in table is increasing, we want this to be mapped dynamically in entity class with @Column. we don't want to add @Column and it's corresponding field name in Entity class(marked with @Entity) everytime we add a new column in a table, we want it to read the column name from some constant variable separated with comma and get it mapped to @Entity class dynamically.